# Is JSF is a framework or an API?

Tags: java, jsf

somebody says JSF is a framework. Others says it's an API. What is it?

Comment: Please describe in your own words the definition of a "framework" and an "API" and tell why you think that JSF wouldn't be the one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its both.
Java Server Faces is a Web-framework for building web applications in Java.
It is a part of Java EE specification, that's why people also call it as API.
But official oracle documentations describes it as a Java EE technology, an API containing specification to build web applications .
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html

> JavaServer Faces technology is a server-side component framework for building Java  technology-based web applications.
>
> JavaServer Faces technology consists of the following:
>
> An API for representing components and managing their state; handling events, server-side validation, and data conversion; defining
> page navigation; supporting internationalization and accessibility;
> and providing extensibility for all these features
>
> Tag libraries for adding components to web pages and for connecting components to server-side objects

Comment: J2EE died 7 years ago. Why do you keep calling it as such?

Comment: @BalusC : Sorry Old habit :) I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

JSF is a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) as well as an API. It is an application framework, which helps you in designing and structuring your web applications.

> JavaServer Faces (JSF) is a Java specification for building
>   component-based user interfaces for web applications.